# PHP sending emails

Tags: php, windows, email

In my application we have a lengthy script that writes multiple records to a database, copies multiple files from one location on the server to another then sends multiple emails.

Weve noticed that intermittently the process will timeout. After some debugging we noted the timeouts generally occur during sending the mail, we are using PHP mail() and its a hosted Windows server. the host said that the CPU usage seems to spike during this script, would that make sense? I didnt think mail was that intensive?

I was thinking it might be better to queue the mail, we cant get Pear running so cant use mail_queue, but I was thinking we just write the email data to the database then setup a cron/scheduled task to run a script every night to process the first record of the table, after it sends the email it deletes the record, then re-runs itself therefore avoiding timeouts?? Maybe this is a cumbersome solution also.. any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On linux you have a script timeout parameter that you can change, I have no idea about windows. If you can not, you could just make the script send a certain amount (x, 10 for example) of mails, which would be below the timeout linit, and then call itself to send the x next mails no ?

Comment: you can change the timeout of the script but the queue its a more flexible solution. Dont send just one, drupal send a couple of them every time cron run, the amount will depend on the server overload, the connection, the size of the email, etc. just test the script dont die before you send X emails.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using SwiftMailer for sending all your email. You can send batches with it.

http://www.swiftmailer.org

If you have LOTS of email to send, a queue system is best.